# Whether the user can edit the preferences file?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

Is there a way that user with root device could modify shared preferences file ? For example with Text editor .
My app store encrypted string and some counter inside this file and this values shouldn't be edited !
If this files could be edit with editor, is there anywhere else that i could store this values ?

And for more detail preferences mode is set to `MODE_PRIVATE` if it will help.

**Short version**

1.Is there a way that preferences file could be edited ?

2.If yes where could this values be saved instead .

Comment: Yes, they can be edited on a rooted device. You can store them in database and then encrypt the database using SQLCipher. Have a look: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Thanks . Is SQLCipher fast enough to run in runtime like preferences?

Comment: Performance is pretty much similar to an unencrypted database.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try encrypting your Shared Preferences.

https://prashantsolanki3.github.io/Secure-Pref-Manager/

This is a very easy to use library which automatically encrypts and decrypts your shared preferences.

```
SecurePrefManager.with(this)
            .set("user_name")
            .value("LoremIpsum")
            .go();
```

Comment: does this library encrypt the preferences values or preferences file . I mean i don't want that the user open preference file .  I encrypted values by myself

Comment: @behrooz No, it doesn't encrypt the preference file but you can easily encrypt your preferences using any encryption technique you want, also you can easily save and retrieve your shared preferences with just one line of code.

Comment: Ok , thanks . i will keep it in mind ;) maybe try it for next project .